# Prop validation with interfaces in Nuxt.js with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am building a website using Nuxt.js (including Vue.js v2) with TypeScript. I would like to use `interface`s for checking if the data passed to components via `props` has the correct structure. Unfortuntely, it seems like TypeScript doesn't check anything. There are 'no issues' even though I pass the wrong data to the component. Here's an example.

The data in the base component:

```
data() {
    return {
        dropdownData: [
            false, // enforced wrong type
            {
                title: 'Title',
                subtitle: 'Subtitle',
            },
        ],
    };
}
```

The component where the data is being passed into:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Vue, { PropType } from 'vue';
    import { DropdownDataInterface } from '~/interfaces/DropdownDataInterface';

    export default Vue.extend({
        props: {
            dropdownData: {
                type: Array as PropType<Array<DropdownDataInterface>>,
                required: true,
            },
        },
    });
</script>
```

And the interface:

```
export interface DropdownDataInterface {
    title: string,
    subtitle: string,
}
```

My .tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "lib": [
            "ESNext",
            "ESNext.AsyncIterable",
            "DOM",
        ],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "~/*": [
                "./*",
            ],
            "@/*": [
                "./*",
            ],
        },
        "types": [
            "@nuxt/types",
            "@nuxtjs/axios",
            "@nuxtjs/auth-next",
            "@types/node",
            "nuxt-i18n",
        ],
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        ".nuxt",
        "dist",
    ],
}
```

Thanks a lot!